# Indexerror in Python for unknown reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I made connect 4, and Im trying to work out an algorithm to determine the winner. The one below determines the horizontal winner although for some reason an error occurs when the counters are positioned vertically like this.
What causes this error and how do I fix it?

board[5][5] == 1 (red chip)

board[4][5] == 1 (red chip)

board[3][5] == 1 (red chip) WHEN THIS IS PLACED ERROR CAUSED

```
#Check for horizontal win   
 for y in range(6):
        for x in range(7 - 3):
            if board[x][y] == 1 and board[x+1][y] == 1 and board[x+2][y] == 1 and board[x+3][y] == 1:
                return True
```

[image: Game Image]ERROR:

```
  if board[x][y] == 1 and board[x+1][y] == 1 and board[x+2][y] == 1 and board[x+3][y] == 1:
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

UPDATE:
That worked but now the vertical test isn't working, what have I done?

```
# check vertical spaces
for x in range(6):
    for y in range(7 - 3):
        if board[x][y] == 1 and board[x][y+1] == 1 and board[x][y+2] == 1 and board[x][y+3] == 1:
            return True
```

UPDATE 2: Index error when I arranaged vertical, occurs when chips are in same position as below

## check vertical spaces

```
for x in range(6):

    for y in range(7 - 3):

        if board[y][x] == 1 and board[y+1][x] == 1 and board[y+2][x] == 1 and board[y+3][x] == 1:

            return True
```

Comment: So how do i resolve this?

Comment: but then checking for horizontal wins wont work?

Comment: @Rawing I didn't see the entire board, you're right

Comment: @AngusRyan Are you sure your board has the correct dimensions? Maybe you have to index it as `board[y][x]` instead of `board[x][y]`?

Comment: `x`,, strangely, seems to indicate the *vertical* axis. That said: you should find the lowest red disk and then check *up*, not *down*. Change your tests to `x-1` and so on.

Comment: that worked, but now check what I've updated above please, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the dimensions of your board is mixed. The picture you posted gives the inserted chips inserted in a vertical order with changing y.

```
board[5][5] == 1 (red chip)

board[4][5] == 1 (red chip)

board[3][5] == 1 (red chip) # Like so
```

So your board layout should actually be accessed with `Board[y][x]`.

But when you are searching the horizontal space, you look the Board up with `Board[x][y]`. Try changing that to

```
#Check for horizontal win   
 for y in range(6):
        for x in range(7 - 3):
            if board[y][x] == 1 and board[y][x + 1] == 1 and board[y][x + 2] == 1 and board[y][x + 3] == 1:
                return True
```

Edit: To fix vertical, just switch x and y as we solved horizontal check problem

Edit2: Make sure to print and check the indices while using negative terms, too big numbers would give you index error but negative numbers would not give you any errors in list indices. And you would not realize the problem until your win check fails.

Comment: Switch the search layout to be `Board[y][x]`, your's is `Board[x][y]` as you see. This can happen to many programmers new to gaming, I have some experience with pygame and even I had a very hard time trying not to confuse the Board access order while I was writing a chess game.

Comment: thanks for your help I appreciate it, but when I did what we did above the index error arose again. Read update

Comment: @AngusRyan If you are checking the chips from bottom to top, you should use y, y-1, y-2, y-3, instead of y y+1 y+2 etc.. Because the most bottom row is actually `Board[6][x]` not `Board[0][x]`. And don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if it helped you, good luck in your game.